# consistincy of the estimator for the standard error in the wald intervall

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

recall that the wald intervall is as   $\bar{X}_n - \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} z_\alpha <p<\bar{X}_n + \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} z_\alpha$
to make a confidence intervall out of it , we estimate $\sigma$ with is equal to $\sqrt{(1-p)p}$ with $\sqrt{(1-\bar{X}_n)\bar{X_n}}$
I am looking to,prove the consistency of that estimation, any idea?

Comment: what's your idea?

Comment: well, first of all , if i prove the consistency for \sigma² , can i say it stands for \sigma

Comment: can i say  , because \bar{X}_n converges in probability to p than 1-\bar{X}_n converges in probability to 1-p and therefore (1-\bar{X}_n)\bar{X}_n converges in probability to 1(1-p)

Comment: If $X_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} X$ then for any continuous function $g(.)$, $g(X_n) \overset{P}{\rightarrow} g(X)$. But you've to be little careful e.g. suppose $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ then you can not talk about $\sqrt{X_n}$ if $X_n$ takes negative values with positive probability.

Comment: allright , very very helpful. i ve got it, thx a lot